# Getting the JSON Patch of featured image from Wordpress API CALL with FlutterFlow

Tags: flutter, jsonpath, wordpress-rest-api, flutterflow

I am trying to get the featured image link from an api call to my Wordpress page. The api call works well and the JSON Path should be something like this:

**$[:]._embedded.wp:featuredmedia[:].link**

I am doing it with FLUTTERFLOW and everytime I write the two dots after “wp” it gets red and says “End of input expected”. So I can not get this information.

I have tried many possibilities like:

**$[:]._embedded.wp[:]featuredmedia[:].link**

**$[:]._embedded.wp”:”featuredmedia[:].link**

Etc.

But it gets red everytime.

Could you help me with that?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: try this: `[your-data]._embedded['wp:featuredmedia']['0'].source_url`

Comment: I did it with this code: $[:]._embedded['wp:featuredmedia'][:].source_url

Comment: ok, so works now?

Comment: Yes… it works!!!

Answer (score 0):

The solution was:

$[:]._embedded['wp:featuredmedia'][:].source_url